# Where can I see the date I created my Gmail account?

Tags: gmail

Well, it's a long time I'm using my Gmail account. Today, I had a talk with my friends about the date we created our Gmail accounts and we all had some guesses about it. Is there any option in Gmail info/settings where I can see the date I created my account?

Comment: You could try searching for the email with the invitation to join Gmail, if you did’t deleted it.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Gmail, like most email systems, sends you a welcome email as part of the account creation process. If you didn't delete it, that will be the first message in your account with the "all mail" label.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Go to *Settings* → **Forwarding and POP/IMAP**
2. See the **POP download:** → **1. Status: POP is enabled** for all mail that has arrived since xx/xx/xx

**EDIT:**

The most appropriate solution (as of now) is-

1. Go to:  https://www.google.com/settings/takeout
2. Click "**Create an archive**"

   [image]
3. Click on "**Google+ circles** > **Transfer your Google+ connections to another account**"

   [image]
4. You'll see the account creation date

   [image]

Comment: I just checked and there's nothing to see. What if you don't have POP enabled?

Comment: If you don't have the POP3 activated, then enable it and save settings. Afterwards, return to settings again. Then you will see what @Sahil is describing.

Comment: Even if you disabled POP, you can just re-enable it temporarily to find the date. Just select Enable POP for all mail including those already downloaded.

Comment: Good answer sahil. Is this the date you've created the gmail or the date you have received your first mail? Anyway, gmail sends every user the first email to welcome, so both dates must be same!

Comment: yes exactly, they are same !

Comment: 1) Using the date in the POP3 settings does not necessarily yield a correct date.
E.g. I joined Gmail during the beta invite phase sometime in 2005, but I get a date with 2002 there. That's because I later imported old mails with that date from my local Thunderbird client. 2) If you hover over the "1-100 of X,XXX", there's an option to show "oldest" or "newest" to quickly reverse the chronological order.

Comment: @user44612 the chronological order doesn't change. If you click "oldest" this will take you a page showing the oldest message for that label at the bottom.

Comment: The feature to transfer of circles data to another account and the display of the date in the POP settings were retired.

Comment: Neither of these solutions works. This was once the correct answer, but it no longer is. There is no date displayed next to the "Status: POP is enabled" (mine was disabled by default but even if I enable it, Save Changes and return - as described by @JacobJanTuinstra - no date is displayed). Moreover, the Google Takeout method also no longer works.

Answer (score 7):

This is the only conclusive answer there is to give about this topic:

1. Go to google.com/takeout and sign-in with your current Google
   Account.
2. Now click the link that says “Transfer your Google+ connections to
   another account”
3. Google will once again require your account password. Sign-in and on
   the next screen you’ll see you Google Account creation

With reference to this article: [Find the Creation Date of your Google Account](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-creation-date/20747/)

Comment: What if you had a Google account before you signed up for Gmail?

Comment: The OP's question concerns Gmail. How does this relate to a Google account? Do you mean Google Apps?

Comment: @AlEverett: see comment.....

Comment: Since [4th December 2014](http://www.googleplusdaily.com/2014/11/google-circles-connections-account.html), the transfert of Google+ connections isn't available anymore.

Comment: This solution no longer works.

Answer (score 5):

the method is very simple:

1. open Gmail
2. click on "all mail"
3. the message in the upper right hand corner of the window will say "1-100 of xx,xxx"
4. divide xx,xxx by 100 and round up. That is the last page number (Y)
5. change the url by adding /pY  so it reads .../..#all/pY
6. My first message is from 3/18/2005 and has the subject "Gmail is different. Here's what you need to know"

Comment: Did you suppose that I've not moved my mails to different folders? I mean I have a few mails in my inbox and all the other mails are in their related folder.

Comment: The "all mail" label shows all the mail, no matter what label if any was attached to a message. Gmail, like most email systems, sends you a welcome email as part of the account creation process.

Comment: I deleted that mail the day I created the account on gmail.

Comment: I imported a lot of email messages from old email systems. I have a significant amount of email that pre-dates the creation of Gmail. This method is not reliable. Certainly that welcome message, if it exists in my mailbox, is not on the last page of "All Mail".

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I searched for "gmail is different" in my gmail (including the double quotes), which found the welcome email.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers proposed several ways to find the creation date. Following, there is a summary

1. Gmail welcome message.

This could be the easiest method and could work for many users but it's not reliable because the message could be deleted, the Gmail service could has been added after the account was created (i.e. Youtube accounts) or removed and added several times.

2. Date in the Gmail POP settings.

This was retired.

3. Date in the Transfer of Google+ connections to another account

This was retired.

Comment: @pnuts : I have an account from around 2008 to which I enabled and disabled POP several times. At this time it's enabled and it doesn't show the date.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack of @mhoran_psprep's answer. Just visit the following URL -

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#all/p9999

Well, it's a safe guess that you don't have more than 999900 mails. Gmail will redirect you to the last page of your inbox, which will have the first 50 emails you ever received.

Comment: It didn't work, Did you suppose that I've not moved my mails to different folders? I mean I have a few mails in my inbox and all the other mails are in their related folder.

Also I remember I've removed my first mail which I received from gmail :D

Comment: Possible. It only searches inside Inbox(you can see it in the url). Try searching inside the "All Mails" folder with this url https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#all/p9999. This will search all your emails including all labels, not only inbox.

Answer (score 1):

Ways have changed over years, so there is the one working now.

1. Go to [Google Takout](http://google.com/takeout)
2. Sign in with your account
3. Click "Create an archive" (located in top right corner)
4. Scroll down to "Google+ Circles"
5. Click "Edit"
6. Click "Transfer your Google+ connections to another account"
7. On that page you'll find creation date of your Google account

Comment: Confirmed. This seems to be the best way at the moment.

Comment: No longer works.

Answer (score 1):

As of June of 2016, none of the methods here worked for me.

I did, however, find a workaround that might work for some (only if you have *not* changed your initial password, however):

Open your [Google account](https://myaccount.google.com) (FYI, this page has the following header: **Control, protect, and secure your account, all in one place**).

Look in the **Sign-in & security** box and click the **Signing in to Google** link therein.

On the ensuing **Signing in to Google** page, look in the **Password & sign-in method** box and observe the date your password was last changed.  If you haven't ever changed your gmail password, said date will most likely be the date that you created said account.

Answer (score 0):

All the current answers are outdated.

I was able to approximate this by searching something like:

```
before:2005/01/01
```

and continually decreasing the date until I zeroed in on the original email. If you are like me, and you have deleted the welcome email, this is your best bet.

Comment: This isn't very useful when you've imported email messages from before you had a Gmail account.

Comment: @ale it's more useful for me than all the existing answers here, most of which 100% don't work.

Answer (score -3):

```
from:google.com
```

Go to search in your Gmail and type `from:google.com`. This returns the invitation email sent by Google the day you created your account (if you haven’t deleted that message already).